# Angular App Shell build fails due to third party libraries

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular8, app-shell

I'm having trouble getting Angular App Shell working.
So I followed the instructions and configured universal project.
Then I also set up App Shell and can see that the configuration at the bottom part of my angular.json is good.
But now when I run

```
ng run proj:app-shell
```

I get the error that **window is undefined**.
The error makes sense because I use third party libraries (ckeditor in this case) which use window directly, but window cannot be accessed from serverside Node.js environment.

However I'm not sure why I get this error because ckeditor is used inside a different component which should NOT be part of app-shell.

Here's my app.component.html

```
<app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
<div class="page-body" [ngClass]="{'sidebar-expanded': (sidebarExpanded | async)}">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-viewport">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ngx-spinner type="ball-grid-beat" color="#696ffb" bdColor="rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8)" size="medium"></ngx-spinner>
```

None of the app-nav-menu, app-sidebar and ngx-spinner components use ckeditor!
The ckeditor is used inside text-element-component which is inside ElementsModule that I import inside app.module.ts

```
import { ElementsModule } from './elements/elements.module';
```

But why is that failing for my app-shell build, which should not use app.module.ts, but app.server.module.ts instead, right?
Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I've wasted a lot of hours on this. The problem was ckeditor script referred to window immediately when loading so that it crashed during the following line:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

I used dynamic import inside the component constructor instead:

```
import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic').then(e => { this.editor = e; });
```